# Django: Check if value in list

Tags: django

I have a QuerySet with several entries `order.order_items.all`. I want to check in my template if any of these items in my list contain the foreign_key discount. After one is found, I want to display that a discount_code was used for the order. How would you solve this?

Example:
`<QuerySet [OrderItem: #k9ukvrfvjk - 1x Test Ticket 1, OrderItem: #k9ukvrfvjk - 1x Test Ticket 2]>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing it in Template, I think its better to do it in the view. For example:

```
context['discount'] = order.order_items.filter(discount_id=<discount_id>).exists()
return render(request, 'template', context=context)
```

and in template:

```
{% if discount %}
 // discounted related codes
{% endif %}
```

#### Update

Maybe you can get it simply by:

```
{% item in order.order_items.all %}
    {% if item.discount %}
        {{ item.discount.discount_code }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```